# How to get the same number of frames from Librosa STFT?

Tags: python, numpy, librosa

I'm trying to create a dataset that consists of Numpy arrays generated from WAV files. I'm able to get all of the individual WAV files into Numpy arrays, but I can't combine into a single Numpy array because they are all slightly different shapes. First dimension is that same for all, but the second dimension(number of frames) varies slightly.

To convert from WAV to Numpy I'm using librosa.stft. The only method I can come up with is to pad each Numpy with zeros to match the max number of frames. This would require me to iterate over each array(3000) and each row within each array to pad each row. There must be a better way.

This is the code to iterate through the WAV files, convert to spectrogram, then save as Numpy array

```
def process(directory):
    # Load file
    for file in os.listdir(directory):
        f = os.path.join(directory, file).replace("\\", r"/")
        x, sr = librosa.load(f, sr=22050)
        # Covert to spectrogram
        X = librosa.stft(x)
        print(X.shape)
        spectrgoram = np.abs(X)
        # Save file
        np.save(f"C:/Python/GANs/Sound_Digit_Gan/Data2/{file}",spectrgoram)
        
process(directory)
```

As the shapes of X are printed these are few examples of the values:
(1025, 23)
(1025, 29)
(1025, 26)
(1025, 34)
(1025, 26)
(1025, 27)
(1025, 40)
(1025, 22)
(1025, 25)
(1025, 24)
(1025, 35)

Then when I try to create my train dataset by using the below:

```
directory = "C:/Python/GANs/Sound_Digit_Gan/Data2/"
train = []

for f in os.listdir(directory):
  file = os.path.join(directory, f).replace("\\", r"/")
  #print(file)
  array = np.load(file)
  #print(array.shape)
  train.append(array)
  
train = np.array(train)
```

I get the error:
`ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1025,13) into shape (1025,)`
I believe this is because the arrays are not all the same shape. How can I get the same shape, but not lose the audio signal data?

Comment: Why do you want/need to get the same sizes? (there are good reasons for this, but sometimes there are alternatives as well - like chopping up into fixed-length analysis windows)

Comment: I'm trying to train a ML model, which requires the same input shapes. Chopping into fixed length intervals might work. Going to try that.

Answer (score 0):

Standardizing the size along the time-dimension is a common preprocessing step in audio machine learning. So the librosa library includes a handy function for it: [librosa.util.fix_length](https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.util.fix_length.html).